# What does "yet" mean, in this phrase?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was updating the software running on my computer, and I noticed that the description of one of the updates contained the following phrase:

> this is the best iTune yet

What does *yet* mean in that phrase? What is the difference between that phrase, and *this is the best iTune*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It basically means "so far", or "up until now":

> *This is the best iTunes so far.*

I'd like to add that *yet* in the context of "the best X yet" is usually used when describing:

- something fairly new onto the scene,
- made by someone with an established track record of success,
- with hints that there may be more to come.

When describing something older, particularly in the twilight of a career or a product's life, you'd be more likely to use the word *ever*, instead of *yet*.

For example, I probably would **not** say:

> *Gimme Shelter* is the best Rolling Stones song yet!

because that song was release in 1969. Instead, I would proclaim:

> *Gimme Shelter* is the best Rolling Stones song ever!

Moreover, I'm not too sure I'd say:

> *When You've Got Trouble* is the best Liz Longley song yet!

because Liz is an emerging artist without a large library of music to her credit. Instead, I'd probably be more likely to say:

> *When You've Got Trouble* is my favorite Liz Longley song.

Lastly, I'm pretty sure I wouldn't say:

> Heath Ledger as the Joker is his best performance yet.

because Mr. Ledger has passed away, and there won't be any future roles that may top his performance in *The Dark Knight*. I'd probably say instead:

> Heath Ledger as the Joker was his best performance.

But, assuming I'm a fan of The Black Keys, I could see myself saying:

> "El Camino" by The Black Keys is their best album yet!

because the album is fairly new, the group has put out a decent number of albums, and there is no sign of an immenent breakup of the band.

Comment: One of your best answers yet!

Answer (score 2):

In this phrase it means 'up to this point in time'.

Meaning that it is the best version of such thing that we know of.

Comment: (implying there may be better in the future, maybe even there are ones in the works already but this is the best available)

Answer (score 0):

Yet is telling us information in the present time.

Comment: May you expand your answer? As it is, it's not much clear.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Please see [_How do I write a good answer to a question?_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7656/205162)